# Как выделить диаметр в графе?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx

Как, имея полный граф G с 4 вершинами, найти его диаметр и выделить этот диаметр красным цветом, используя Networkx и Python?

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае - очень просто, берёте **любое** ребро - это и будет диаметр полного графа K4. Для полного величина диаметра всегда единица.

---

В общем случае для нахождения диаметра можно найти кратчайшие расстояния между всеми парами вершин (алгоритмы Форда-Беллмана или Флойда–Уоршелла) и выбрать наибольшее

Comment: Так-то оно так, но моя проблема это закрасить ребро по ходу его "поиска".

Comment: Я проверить не могу, у меня никакого рисования в питоне не установлено, но у ребра, похоже, есть атрибут цвета: G.add_edge(1, 2, color='red', weight=0.84, size=300)